# How to evaluate a function directly?

Tags: c++, class

Title may not make any sense but I dont really know how to explain this.
I have a class called polynomial and lets say I defined a polynome called `p1` which is `2x+4`. What I want to do is calculate `p1(5)` directly. I dont want anything like `double calculate (polynomial)` etc I want to be able to calculate my polynom with `p1(x)`.

I hope my question is clear

Comment: You might be looking for `operator()`.

Comment: Thanks, didnt know I can do this.

Answer (score 11):

Overload the function-call operator:

```
struct polynomial
{
    double a, b;
    polynomial(double m, double n) : a(m), b(n) { }  // represents "a * x + b"

    double operator()(double x) const
    {
        return a * x + b;
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
polynomial p(2.5, 3.8);

double val = p(1.0);
```

Answer (score 5):

By overloading `operator()` you can "call" an object just like you would call a function:

```
struct polynomial {
    int operator()(int x)
    {
        /* calculate */
    }
};

int main()
{
    polynomial p;
    int x = p(5);
}
```